# Chrome extension cannot read site data for LinkedIn

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that will parse a person's first and last name and company name from their Linkedin profile. I've added `https://linkedin.com/*` to my matches array in `manifest.json` but the extension says that it cannot read or modify the site's data. If I add any other site to the array, it works. Does LinkedIn have some type of Chrome extension blocking in their source?

manifest.json contents:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/derp.js"],
      "matches": ["https://linkedin.com/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's `https://www.linkedin.com/*` (see [Chrome address bar no longer shows protocol or www subdomain](https://superuser.com/a/1498561))